# javascript nao retorna ao concatenar link

Tags: php, javascript

tenho um link que muda dinamicamente, o problema é quando eu faço a concatenação nao retona nada

```
        <?php
            $user_id = 1;
        ?>


        <div id="link-bt">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="seguir('link-bt','Seguir','<?=$user_id;?>');">Seguir</a>  
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        function seguir(id,valor,user_id){

            var insert = document.getElementById(id);

            if(valor == "Seguir"){

                insert.innerHTML = '<a onClick=cancelar("link-bt","Cancelar","'+user_id+'"); href="javascript:void(0);>Cancelar</a></li>';

            }

        }
        function cancelar(id,valor,user_id){

            var insert = document.getElementById(id);

            if(valor == "Cancelar"){

                insert.innerHTML = '<a onClick=seguir("link-bt","Seguir","'+user_id+'"); href="javascript:void(0);>Seguir</a></li>';

            }

        }

        </script>
```

Comment: Isso correto é depende a versão php suporta, e tente `<? echo $user_id; ?>`.

Comment: @KIngRider não é problema com PHP ,pois fiz um teste utilizando o alerta("user_id"); e teve sucesso

Comment: ok e mas já resolveu? se precisar te ajudo me conversa skype live:sandro.alvares ... código de teste assim `alert(user_id)` ou `console.log(user_id)` rss.. veja comentário disse @lvcs abaixo.

Comment: Tudo certo aqui, valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Ajuste só o id no html (`onclick=...`) para `'<?=$user_id;?>'`. Acho que é isto que quer

```html
<div id="link-bt">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="seguir('link-bt','Seguir', 5);" id="my_link">Seguir</a>  
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        function seguir(id,valor,user_id){

            var insert = document.getElementById('my_link');

            if(valor == "Seguir"){

                insert.innerHTML = 'Cancelar';
                insert.onclick = function() {
                    cancelar("link-bt","Cancelar", user_id);
                }
            }

        }
        function cancelar(id,valor,user_id){

            var insert = document.getElementById('my_link');

            if(valor == "Cancelar"){

                insert.innerHTML = 'Seguir';
                insert.onclick = function() {
                    seguir('link-bt','Seguir', user_id);
                }
            }

        }

        </script>
```

Para fazer só esta funcionalidade e aproveitar um pouco do que fez, eu faria assim:

```html
<div id="link-bt">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="mudar_attrs('link-bt','Seguir', 5);" id="my_link">Seguir</a>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function mudar_attrs(id,valor,user_id){
        var insert = document.getElementById('my_link');
        if(valor == "Seguir"){
            insert.innerHTML = 'Cancelar';
            insert.onclick = function() {
                mudar_attrs("link-bt","Cancelar", user_id);
            }
        }
        else {
            insert.innerHTML = 'Seguir';
            insert.onclick = function() {
                mudar_attrs("link-bt", "Seguir", user_id);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: De nada @Php. Ainda acresentei uma solução que para mim, tendo em conta a funcionalidade é melhor. Fazer só uma função em vez de duas.

Comment: Muitos servidores não teem a opção de usar o = para imprimir ados e as tags `<? ?>` dificultam um pouco a legibilidade. Sugiro `<?php echo $user_id; ?>`

Comment: Sim, é verdade. No entanto, esse não era o problema

Comment: Sim, só comentei pra deixar registrado :) porque vi na resposta e no comentário lá em cima

Comment: Obrigado @Ivcs :)

Comment: Simplesmente perfeito!

Comment: hehe @Php Obgado

Comment: @Miguel uma observação, eu sempre usei esse meu método para enviar links dinamicamente, agora com seu método ficou mais simples